# doPut or update through JavaScript and REST

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

This might sound like a stupid question but I am trying to understand what way is better and when is it used. In my project, if I want to update any information, lets say a user profile after he has logged in, then should it be done by submitting information of the form to a servlet in a doPut method and make calls to a helper class that will update database through a query **or** should I make the submit action of the form to a JavaScript function where an Ajax call can make a request to a RESTful resource where I can update database by making call to a same helper class? What are the pros and cons of these approached? Way I see it is that both approaches will contact a database and run an update query. Any help in clearing this is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Whether you use ajax or not depends on if you want to maintain the current page state or not.

Comment: Any scenario example?

Comment: i.e. you don't want the screen to refresh or move to a different url